# Creating a UIView with PanGestureRecognizer and activating it without lifting the finger

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I've created a circle on the screen by creating a UIView at the finger's location when touchesBegan():

*In ViewController:*

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let pos = touch.locationInView(view)

        let radius: CGFloat = touch.majorRadius * 2
        let circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRectMake(pos.x - radius / 2, pos.y - radius / 2, radius, radius))
        view.addSubview(circleView)

    }
}
```

*In CircleView:*

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handlePan:"))
    recognizer.delegate = self
    self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

}
```

This creates the circle, but does not move it immediately when I move my finger. Instead, I have to pick my finger up and place it back on the circle before handlePan() kicks in.

Is there a way to start tracking a pan gesture without lifting the finger that spawned it's parent view, taking into account there may be multiple fingers touching and moving around the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish multiple independent touches by keeping a dictionary of all active touches and creating the circle views in touchesBegan() and updating their position in touchesMoved() by querying that dictionary.

```
var fingerTouches = [UITouch: CircleView]()

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let pos = touch.locationInView(view)

        let radius: CGFloat = touch.majorRadius * 2
        let circle = CircleView(frame: CGRectMake(pos.x - radius / 2, pos.y - radius / 2, radius, radius))
        view.addSubview(circle)

        fingerTouches[touch] = circle

    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let pos = touch.locationInView(view)

        let radius: CGFloat = touch.majorRadius * 2
        fingerTouches[touch]!.frame = CGRectMake(pos.x - radius / 2, pos.y - radius / 2, radius, radius)

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        fingerTouches[touch]!.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you're using both touchesBegan, and a UIPanGestureRecognizer. For best results, use one or the other. If you're going to do it with just a pan gesture (which is what I would do), do the following:

```
func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        //handle creating circle
    } else if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {
        //handle movement
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Two questions/problems with this method: is it able to handle multiple independent touches; and is it able to create the create the circle view immediately when the screen is touched, as opposed to when the finger is moved from its initial position?

I wasn't able to do either with an initial try.

Comment: In order to use gesture recognizers like this, you would need to add the gesture directly onto the circle view itself. Perhaps you could create a tap gesture (or a long press gesture with a very short time) to create the circle and add the gesture,  but then you would still have to hand one off to the other. Hmmm, you may have to use touchesBegan and touchesMoved, or write your own custom gesture.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already created the circle view successfully in method `touchesBegan:withEvent:`

you can

1. Make that circle view a property
2. Move that circle view directly in method `touchesMoved:withEvent:`

This won't require you pick your finger up first

Comment: What about if there is more than one finger touching?